# "I would have ... but" vs "I wanted to ... but."

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

Which construction is more natural? Example sentence:

> I **wanted to/would have** stopped her, but something else did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I **would have** stopped her, but something else did.

Is the better sentence. It's not correct to say

> I wanted to stopped her, but something else did

But even if you corrected it to

> I wanted to stop her, but something else did.

It still makes more sense to say I **would have**, because **wanting** to do something doesn't necessarily voice *intent* to do it. Saying you would have voices your intent to stop her, but then you contradict it by saying something else did.